# Basic authentication with c# in webBrowser Forms Application

Tags: c#, authentication, basic-authentication, explorer

I searched the web for this problem and found always this line as answer:

```
this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("https://username:password@url", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

But this is no longer supported in IE

Now I have implemented this:

```
this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("myurl", System.UriKind.Absolute);
this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
```

Within the function `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` I have the following:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  string username = "myusername";
  string password = "mypassword";
  string auth = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
  string headers = "Authorization: Basic " + auth + "\r\n";
  webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
  webBrowser1.Navigate("https://myurl", "", null, headers);
} // added for completeness by editor
```

This does not load the complete page, and it refreshes every few seconds. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Its refreshing because the documentcompleted will happen each time the page load finishes... so.. each time it will trigger another.

Comment: Is it possible to disable that trigger?

Comment: Yes, on the top of the document completed - eg you could do it the first time only do this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;  .. however, if it needs a password for something else, then that wont work.. I havent looked but there maybe a on responds code check for 401 and provide details

Comment: Great, now it works fine.

Comment: How can I implement a refresh for every e.g. 5 minutes?

Comment: You should google, and if you still dont find it.  Post a new question.